# What does 'corrupted' (world or society) mean?

Tags: modern-world

Several people (several questions and answers) in [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/24266/254) use the word "corrupted", especially applied to "the world" and "society".

- What does the word "corrupted" mean?
- Does it have a standard meaning in Buddhism, or is it idiosyncratic?
  Is it an objective (observable, shareable) property (of the world), or a subjective (personal) feeling?
  Do all schools (or yanas) define it the same way?
  Is it mentioned in any suttas?
- Is it related to the idea that the Buddha's Dharma may (or will be, has been) lost, misinterpreted, over time? Or is it a different perception, applied to "society" rather than "dharma"?
- Why would someone say that the world or society is becoming *more* corrupt? Compared to when and where, or what? Do schools (and/or teachers) differ in their view of whether the world is "progressing", i.e. whether it's improving or regressing?

Comment: Perhaps it is simply an assumed term, like 'suffering', needing no further explication? Does it matter if it has a cause, grows worse or less so? We cannot change it, basically, like dukkha.

Comment: Dukkha is (or was) explained further; starting with the first noble truth. The definition (of "corruption") might matter when people are offering life advice resulting from an observation that the world is corrupt ... as if it *is* corrupt, and as if that's a *shared* observation (i.e. people giving advice understand what "corruption" is being complained of. and vice versa). Also I wondered how the term relates to standard doctrine[s].

Comment: I have been reading about Feyerabend's concept of 'incommensurability'. It reminds me of Cheryl Abram saying that everyone has their own world. Take the concept of 'Diunital' and wrap that up with Nonduality. Presto! I guess we still need to attempt to clarify terms.

Comment: I think a word like "dusty" for example makes sense (as a metaphor) in a Buddhist context because it's used several times in the context of well-known scriptures (suttas). To the extent that suttas are trustworthy, it's not only a clear metaphor but a (morally) good one. But is society's being "corrupt" such a "good" description? I don't recognise it as an obviously-true description, as a well-known description, nor even as a (morally) good description, virtuous, skilled: perhaps it's hate-filled, proud or hurt, I don't know. Anyway if it's dharmic and helpful I wanted to understand it better.

Comment: I recall Zen using the image of dust on a mirror. Rumi uses the phrase "polishing the mirror" also. It is possible that the word 'dusty' arose from a single usage in some distant past scripture and has spread. For me, the essence of the word 'corruption' is the decay after death, meaning that some principle that was preserving the 'life' of people (their morality or whatever) has died, and now things are decaying. Anything less dire does not need a word like corrupt, and so dusty misses the mark. I regret that I have no suttas to steer you toward.

Comment: "Dusty" is in the suttas too: as, the Buddha's agreeing to teach "for the sake of those who have little dust in their eyes" (i.e. who can benefit from the dharma); and. "the householder's life is a dusty path" (compared to "going forth" as a monk). So the dust of the world, apparently, or the world as dust: blinding, fruitless, also unable to satisfy "craving" (literally "thirst"). The English word "corruption", to me, has the meaning you describe: putrefaction after death, also "sundered". And it's Christian, it describes the Fall of Man (and more generally the fall of the world), implying...

Comment: ... that a system which used to be good has acquired some evil intent. Is that Buddhist? I think the "original sin" according to Buddhism is confusion or ignorance (not knowing what's "good"), in Judeo-Christianity maybe it's disobedience (and "knowledge of good and evil, apparently!), also sexuality and shame. So if that's like Christian, is "corrupt" used in Buddhism, and if so where and what does it mean there? And is it true that, why might you say that, "the world" or "society" is becoming *more* corrupt? Is that a socially conservative (society used to be better, now getting worse) view?

Comment: Is a view of whether or not it *is* getting worse a feature of various schools? Do Mahayana sects, for example, see it as getting any better?

Comment: Socrates said that "these young people" are less worthy than their elders, so the decline has been going on since then, apparently. It squares with the idea of decline, if every generation sees things as getting worse. I think a lot of things have improved in the last few hundred years. Ancient suttas probably won't have much to say about recent developments.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's idiosyncratic.  Each school has a somewhat different take on it.  In Zen, we often refer to corruption as "red dust".  Han Shan, for instance, refers to it often:

> I was born just thirty years ago,
>   but I’ve wandered a million miles already. 
>   Along the River through the green grass on the 
>   banks, out to the borderlands, where the red dust roils.

I think the footnote in my copy of his poetry does an excellent job of explaining this idea:

> "The word we usually translate as “dust,” or “the red dust,” is a
>   conventional epithet for the klesas, or “defilements,” of life in the
>   everyday world, everything from simple dirt, to the deep moral
>   defilements we accept in the compromises and little hypocrisies of
>   everyday lay living."

From *Cold Mountain Poems* translated by J.P Seaton

Comment: that poem is: 1出生三十年，2當遊千萬里。3行江青草合，4入塞紅塵起。wouldn't a translation as this better than that? *1Though for thirty years I was born, 2yet millions miles I've roamed. 3Tracking along the river green grasses spread but furl; 4entering the border the red dusts swirl*. classical Chinese poem always goes with rhythm, also with graphical beauty like colors and patterns in words, and embedded meanings. i guess 境界 (image reflecting state of mind?), 意象 (image as metaphorical story-telling?) maybe is not as an element in English literature, however it's the very spirit in Chinese. i'm no expert though :)

Comment: Ya got me.  I don't speak Chinese in any form!

Comment: I like @Mishu米殊 translation, but for English-only reader, the other is a bit more clear.

Comment: @Mishu米殊 I often like (or prefer) a literal word-for-word translation, without the translation's choosing or adding extra English words to make it rhyme or rhythm or grammar -- so something like, "born thirty years | when travel 1000 miles | ... | ...". What are the last two lines, translated in that style?

Comment: Ya got me too @nocomprende :) *"for English-only reader, the other is a bit more clear"* that's the puzzle I try to solve, for I got the meaning in Chinese therefore it's a bit difficult to fall back to *unclear* understanding - when examining my own work; plus other issues

Comment: @ChrisW Using google translate :)? // 3 is *walking at the side of the big river* [河 is narrower; this one: 江 is wider, therefore we got Yellow River (黃**河**), Yangtze River (長**江**)], the poet's legs *divided the tall grasses then they furled back after passed*. 4 is *entering the country border* (塞) (Ancient China the border divided by the Great Wall, outside was non-Middle-Kingdom culture) [here it's a metaphor of entering Samsara]; Red Dust is the world, for Chang'an was like modern New York, the busy carriages stirred up dusts in the setting sun looked red, also **dust** is translation...

Comment: ...of Paramanu (微塵 micro-dust), the Buddhist idea of smallest indivisible unit, combined a new etymology Red Dust with very very rich literature and cultural meanings. Therefore the last one is a metaphor the ups and downs of the world the drama began when one entered Samsara. These four are just part of a long poem. // I was trying the word-for-word, it's more honest than trying to digest then *rewrite a piece of translation*. I only choosing among the words corresponding to the meaning with better rhythm, or re-arrange the words in one sentence to get the rhythm --

Comment: [3]   行 walked /  江 river /  青 green /  草 grass /  合 close   [4]  入 entered /  塞 border /  紅 red /  塵 dust /  起 rises

Comment: @Mishu米殊 [Here is](http://www.ahapoetry.com/AHI%20frog%20art.html) an example of  poem translated word-for-word: "ancient pond | frog jumps in | sound of water". I've seen more "poetic" translations with English grammar added, like "Breaking the silence of an antique pond, a frog jumped into water" ... I like the first, simple version.

Comment: @ChrisW think i've seen this poem somewhere long ago... will take time to read and find the *old* Japanese (which is in fact Chinese :), thanks. i can see why, because Chinese doesn't have "grammar", no tense, no need to use *the, a, to, for*... subject etc. only key words, very condense meaning in short verse because any word that's just filling the space is out :)). that's why it's a pain to read long scholastic thesis... imagine the Tao Te Jing has 4999 words only, Art of War only about 6000. Macro Polo said learning 500 words by heart would be able to read Classical Chi works, try :)

Comment: @Mishu米殊 Re. Basho's poem, a commentary I read said it was about hearing-consciousness. Re. Chinese, I read that Chinese also doesn't distinguish noun from verb: so a pair of ideograms like "mountain + running" might mean "I run a mountain" or "a mountain run". So: simpler, maybe better than English. Also fewer different words (or more compounded words) -- I heard someone complain that English is difficult to learn because it has completely different words like "car, bus, bicycle, truck, taxi, etc.", saying that in Chinese those words are instead "vehicle, public vehicle, self vehicle, etc.".

Comment: ya got it 2 @ChrisW ! another piece for you to contemplate: 恰恰用心時，恰恰無心用；無心恰恰用，常用恰恰無。this is part of the stanza of Lazy/Dào Róng Ch'an master when he enlightened. almost same characters, arranging in different order, in perfect meaning :) [my advice is to get google translating each word and put them together as verse. you might get enlightened by this, yo!]

Answer (score 2):

The translation of "corruption" & "corrupt" is found in many places in the Pali suttas, such as:

> As to this, bhikkhus, there is a threefold corruption and failure of bodily kamma, arisen from unwholesome volition, having a painful outcome and result; a fourfold corruption and failure of verbal kamma, arisen from unwholesome volition, having a painful outcome and result; and a threefold corruption and failure of mental kamma, arisen from unwholesome volition, having a painful outcome and result.
>
> It is, bhikkhus, because of the threefold corruption and failure of bodily kamma, arisen from unwholesome volition … or it is because of the fourfold corruption and failure of verbal kamma, arisen from unwholesome volition … or it is because of the threefold corruption and failure of mental kamma, arisen from unwholesome volition, that with the breakup of the body, after death, beings are reborn in the plane of misery, in a bad destination, in the lower world, in hell.
>
> [AN 10.218](https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.218)

While the world can never be perfect, a morally uncorrupted world is described in many places in the Pali suttas, including simply as the Six-Directions & the respective duties/relationship obligations expounded within. A departure from the kammic lawfulness of the Six Directions is a corruption (rather than something "progressive").

> And how, young householder, does a noble disciple cover the six quarters?
>
> The following should be looked upon as the six quarters. The parents should be looked upon as the East, teachers as the South, wife and children as the West, friends and associates as the North, servants and employees as the Nadir, ascetics and brahmans as the Zenith
>
> [DN 31 Sigalovada Sutta The Layperson's Code of Discipline](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html)

Or the Conditions of a Nation's Welfare:

> So long, brahman, as these endure among the Vajjis, and the Vajjis are
> known for it, their growth is to be expected, not their decline.
>
> [DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html)

The cause & condition for the creation & maintenance of the human world is wholesome sexual & family conduct. While the world has periodically engaged in wars & other unwholesome actions, a departure from wholesome sexual & family conduct is the primary cause of the corruption of the human world & regression into an animal, hell &/or hungry ghost world.

> Bhikkhus, these two bright principles protect the world. What are the
> two? Shame and fear of wrongdoing. If, bhikkhus, these two bright
> principles did not protect the world, there would not be discerned
> respect for mother or maternal aunt or maternal uncle's wife or a
> teacher's wife or the wives of other honored persons, and the world
> would have fallen into promiscuity, as with goats, sheep, chickens,
> pigs, dogs, and jackals. But as these two bright principles protect
> the world, there is discerned respect for mother... and the wives of
> other honored persons.
>
> AN 2.9

Comment: The last instruction Milarepa gave his followers is reported to be: *"Act so that you have no cause to be ashamed of yourselves."*